# How can I create a thumbnail with TinyMCE's default video embed code?

Tags: html, video, tinymce, flashvars, flash-video

I'm using TinyMCE to embed an `FLV` video. Using the default media tool with "Flash" selected in the dropdown for "media type", this code is generated:

```
<object width="320" height="240" 
        data="/path/to/tiny_mce/plugins/media/moxieplayer.swf"
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
  <param name="src" value="/path/to/tiny_mce/plugins/media/moxieplayer.swf" />
  <param name="flashvars" value="url=/path/to/video.flv&amp;poster=/" />
  <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
  <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="true" />
</object>
```

It looks like this after saving; white background, invisible until I hover the mouse, then the controls appear:

[image]

The video plays fine. I've tried adding an `<img>` tag inside the `<object>`, and tried adding the path to an image in the `&poster=` parameter, but it doesn't appear. I can't use YouTube. It doesn't have to be with TinyMCE, I can hand edit the HTML.

How can I add a thumbnail? ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YED3A/1/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope you have good day-

in the flash codes, you cans set `wmode="transparent"` and the flahs wite backround willn't be displayed and you can place picture behing where the movies is and set `z-index:-1` so when start playing and video cover pucture here i make example for you to see http://jsfiddle.net/YED3A/4/ is ther

Comment: now how do i make it ajax i tried this heres my codes (function(e,t){var n,r,i=typeof t,o=e.location,a=e.document,s=a.documentElement,l=e.jQuery,u=e.$,c={},p=[],f="1.10.1",d=p.concat,h=p.push,g=p.slice,m=p.indexOf,y=c.toString,v=c.hasOwnProperty,b=f.trim,x=function(e,t){return new x.fn.init(e,t,r)},w=/[+-]?(?:\d*\.|)\d+(?:[eE][+-]?\d+|)/.source,T=/\S+/g,C=/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g,N=/^(?:\s*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*|#([\w-]*))$/,k=/^<(\w+)\s*\/?>(?:<\/\1>|)$/,E=/^[\],:{}\s]*$/,S=/(?:^|:|,)(?:\s*\[)+/g,A=/\\(?:["\\\/bfnrt]|u[\da-fA-F]{4})/g,j=/"[^"\\\r\n]*"|true|false|null|-?(?:\d+\.|)\d+(?:[

Comment: oh is questions of good i alwas use jqury for my ajaxes but also use porptotype for whens you need to colect data first so try that .hope is good day

Comment: nevermind i try it with **`FLASH VIDEO`** now its working perfect only now i need it for **PHP**